# Form loaded with AJAX resets & loses data with reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Update: I have solved issue #1, but I am still not sure how to handle issue #2.**

I am loading an editable HTML table with AJAX and refreshing every 7 seconds. I am refreshing because if the student has "checked in" on their computer, I need to remove the grey filter from their name. However, there are two main problems:

<strike>1. The table contains inputs for the user to select different rows. However, every 7 seconds all of the inputs selected/changed by the user are wiped after AJAX load. [See GIF example of problem here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKxjr.jpg)</strike>

2. If the user is editing a `<span contenteditable='true'>` that information is also wiped every 7 seconds.  [See GIF example of problem here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCwns.jpg)

So what can I do to prevent data loss while the user is in the middle of editing/selecting items? The main reason I am refreshing is to check to see if the student has "checked in" since first page load, so I am open to other solutions. Right now though I am at a complete loss and would appreciate any advice/solutions/explanations.

**Here is the AJAX function:**

```
  var ucid = 1;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const view = urlParams.get('view');

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#content").load("SQL.php?ucid=" + ucid + "&view=" + view);
     setInterval(function() {
      if ($("#content input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
        $("#content").load("SQL.php?ucid=" + ucid + "&view=" + view);
      }
     }, 7000);
  });
```

**The above AJAX function is inserting the** `<table id='list'>` **as seen in the code snippet below.**

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100vw; height: 65px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5F6368;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  body {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px; left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 65px);
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, 1fr) 60px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "content"
      "bottombar"}

#content {overflow: auto;}

/* --------[BOTTOM BAR] -------- */
#bottombar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray}

#bottombar .left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;}

/* Adjusts spacing between links */
#bottombar .left a {margin-right: 12px}

/* Adjusts buttons to be centered */
#bottombar .right {margin-top: -5px}

/* --------[LIST VIEW] -------- */

table#list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse}

#list thead {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;}

#list thead th {padding: 16px;}

#list thead tr {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray}

#list tbody tr {border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}
#list tbody tr:hover{
  transform: scale(1.01);
  background-color: #EADDF8}

/* Formatting for absent students */
#list .absent {filter: grayscale(100%); color: gray;}

/* Positioning for table cells */
#list tbody td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;}

/* Positioning for student pic/name */
#list .student {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;}

/* Formatting/spacing for student pic */
#list .student img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  clip-path: circle();
  margin-right: 10px;}

/* Formatting for editable divs */
[contenteditable="true"]:active,
[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;}

/* Formatting for clicking inside tr */
#list tr:focus-within td {background-color: #E9DCF9}
#list tr:focus-within td input {background-color: #E9DCF9}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<body>
  
  <form id='content'>
    <table id='list'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Student</th>
          <th>Last Seen</th>
          <th>Desk</th>
          <th>Level</th>
          <th>Money</th>
          <th>Pay Rate</th>
          <th>Streak</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>
            <div class='student'>
              <span title='Student ID: 11'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png' loading='lazy'></span>
              <span>Present Student</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><span>1w ago</span></td>
          <td>
            <div class='center'>
              <span><div class='desk' contenteditable='true'>1</div></span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable='true'>3</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            $<span class='money' contenteditable='true'>100</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            $<span class='payRate' contenteditable='true'>10</span>/hr
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class='streak' contenteditable='true'>13</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>
            <div class='student absent'>
              <span title='Student ID: 12'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png' loading='lazy'></span>
              <span>Absent Student</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><span>1w ago</span></td>
          <td>
            <div class='center'>
              <span><div class='desk' contenteditable='true'>1</div></span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable='true'>5</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            $<span class='money' contenteditable='true'>500</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            $<span class='payRate' contenteditable='true'>20</span>/hr
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class='streak' contenteditable='true'>33</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  
  <div id='bottombar'>
    <div class='left'>
      <a href='?view=list'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/icons/i_listview.png'></a>
      <a class="selectall" onclick='selectAll(); chk(this);'>Select All</a>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
      <button id='takeAction' class="button grey-btn" type='button' onclick='actionLaunch("show")' disabled>Take Action</button>
      <button id='selectRandom' class="button purple-btn" type='button' onclick='random("show")'>Random</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: You could check if the user is editing the form, and skip updating it.

Comment: @Barmar good idea, but I'm not sure how to implement. I edited the question to show what I tried..

Comment: First of all, the `if` should be inside the interval function.

Comment: Actually, I think there's no easy way to do this. Even if they're not currently editing the form, they might have edited it and then clicked away. You shouldn't be constantly reloading a page that contains a form.

Comment: Is there some way you can take the form out of the part of the page that's being refreshed?

Comment: @Barmar the main reason I need to refresh is because if the user has "checked in" then I need to remove the "absent" class from ```<div class='student'>``` - however, I am not sure how I would only refresh this part and not the others. I'm open to suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

I won't ponder into why you are refreshing every x seconds just to change a specific element, but if you want to keep the state, you can use `LocalStorage` or `SessionStorage` and add data attributes on your html to use as key:

html:

```
...
<span class="abc" data-key="money" contenteditable=true></span>
<span class="abc" data-key="payRate" contenteditable=true></span>
...
```

js:

```
...
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#content").load("SQL.php?ucid=" + ucid + "&view=" + view);
     const allContentEditable = $('span[contenteditable]');

     for (const ce of allContendEditable) {
       // get the data from sessionStorage and set it in their corresponding tags
       ce.innertText = sessionStorage.getItem(ce.dataset.key);
     }
     
     setInterval(function() {
      if ($("#content input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
        for (const ce of allContendEditable) {
          // get the data from tags and store it in sessionStorage
          sessionStorage.setItem(ce.dataset.key, ce.innerText)
        }

        $("#content").load("SQL.php?ucid=" + ucid + "&view=" + view);
      }
     }, 7000);
  });
```

Keep in mind that if the data is sensitive then you should really think what you are storing in localStorage or sessionStorage!

further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API